# Не получается перейти на зарегистрированную запись по ссылке WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Как сделать доступ по ссылке на собственную зарегистрированню запись? При переходе по определенному слагу переходит на шаблон 404.php.

Вот код functions.php
add_action('init', 'landing_post_types');

```
function landing_post_types(){
    register_post_type('pizza', [
        'labels' => [
            'name'               => 'Пиццы', // основное название для типа записи
            'singular_name'      => 'Пицца', // название для одной записи этого типа
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить новую', // для добавления новой записи
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление пиццы', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактирование пиццы', // для редактирования типа записи
            'new_item'           => 'Новая пицца', // текст новой записи
            'view_item'          => 'Смотреть пиццу', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
            'search_items'       => 'Искать пиццу', // для поиска по этим типам записи
            'not_found'          => 'Не найдено', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
            'parent_item_colon'  => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
            'menu_name'          => 'Пиццы', // название меню
        ],
        'public'              => true,
        'rewrite'            => true,
        'menu_position'       => 25,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-format-quote', 
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'supports'            => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'), // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'
    ]);
}

function landing_show_pizza(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby'     => 'date',
        'order'       => 'DESC',
        'post_type'   => 'pizza'
    );

    return get_posts($args);
}
```

Пробовал менять 'rewrite'на true или на false ничего не помогает, может, нужно что-то другое. Вроде много чего ещё попробовал, все в true ставил, все равно на 404.php кидает.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что значит "зарегестрированню запись"?

Comment: Создание или регистрация новой записи в функции register_post_type, туда передается много параметров, чтобы настроить ее. Подвешивается на хук 'init'

Comment: Запись не может "регистрироваться". Её создают в админке.  Функция `register_post_type` регистрирует ТИП контента. См https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type

Comment: Я просто только начал изучать wordpress по этому в терминологии не але. Да я зарегестрировал тип контента и потом насоздовал записей в админке. У меня кстати все заработало, но я не совсем понимаю почему. Последнее, что я сделал, нажал сохранить в настройках постоянных ссылок и еще переставлял параметры у зарегестрированного типа контента.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как все заработало, но я до сих пор не понял почему. Последнее, что я сделал, это нажал сохранить в настройках постоянных ссылок и вот кстати окончательные параметры, которые я использовал, но помогли не они

```
'public'              => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_rest'        => false,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap'        => true,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'has_archive'         => 'faq',
        'query_var'           => true,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
```